# How to highlight a jsTree node based on a specific value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree, oracle-apex

I am using jsTree to build my tree within Oracle APEX v4.2, which all works fine.

What I am after and unsure how to do is, whenever a node in the tree starts with the letter 'S', within the whole tree, I would like to highlight these nodes only with a background colour of say yellow.

Example of result that I after is seen below where the nodes that I want to have a background colour have been marked with a `<*>`

```
KING
----------JONES
--------------------SCOTT  <*>
--------------------FORD
------------------------------SMITH  <*>
----------BLAKE
--------------------ALLEN
--------------------WARD
--------------------MARTIN
--------------------TURNER
--------------------JAMES
----------SAM  <*>
```

### Updated

An example of the jsTree, not so much of the example I have above can be found here from another thread that Tom assisted me with, here in SO, i.e. jsTree and Oracle APEX - see here:

```
Username: apex_demo
Password: demo
```

http://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=69001:2

Based on this example, which is using the same concepts (jsTree), I would expect that only ***Shelly Noble*** would be highlighted but if there were other names that started with "S", these would also be highlighted with a background colour of yellow.

Comment: Could you please post the HTML output of the jsTree plugin.

Comment: Hi Rory - please see my update above with Oracle APEX link to follow for an example jsTree together with HTML. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the HTML structure of the jsTree example in your question, the following should work:

```
$('#treecontainer a').filter(function() {
    return /^S/i.test($.trim($(this).text()));
}).addClass('highlight'); //amend the class as needed
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/25nPh/)

Comment: Rory, unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working for me, even though the solution you have is correct. I am using IE8, jQuery 1.7.1 but I think I am not sure where to place this code based on the way that the jsTree is being rendered. If you take a look at the first javascript block at this url http://tpetrus.blogspot.be/2013/09/implementing-ajax-tree-in-apex.html - this is the way I have structured the jsTree but once it gets rendered, I'm unsure where to place you solution code? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Rory, pls ignore previous comment. All good, managed to get it all working by placing your code within a callback: { onopen() }. Thanks.